# How can I access multiple content in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to use an webview. 
I use

```
ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/finance/chart?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&biw=1366&bih=390&q=+val[from]+val[to]+&tkr=1&p=5Y&chst=vkc&chs=229x94&chsc=1&ei=VyUXU7j6JaXq0QGh3oG4CQ");
```

**logCat :**

> 03-06 12:50:27.551: D/adnan(14485):  android.webkit.WebView{413ab878 VFEDHVCL ........ 156,340-456,640 #7f0a0010 app:id/chartWebView}

If I use

> ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/finance/chart?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&biw=1366&bih=390&q=CURRENCY:BDTHKD&tkr=1&p=5Y&chst=vkc&chs=229x94&chsc=1&ei=VyUXU7j6JaXq0QGh3oG4CQ");

then it is ok... but i need to use dynamic data not this fixed one.

Comment: You have wrongly written it.. you can use it as :
static_part"+dynamic_part+";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly written it..

You can use it as : `"static_part"+dynamic_part+"`

So you need to write :

```
ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/finance/chart?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&biw=1366&bih=390&q="+val[from]+":"+val[to]+"&tkr=1&p=5Y&chst=vkc&chs=229x94&chsc=1&ei=VyUXU7j6JaXq0QGh3oG4CQ");
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer. But it does not work.

Comment: 1.val[from] & 2.val[to]+ both are dynamic part

Comment: happy to help always.. :)